# Unable to boot USB drive created from Live GNOME 3.4 ISO

Tags: gnome, gnome3, liveusb

I have downloaded GNOME 3.4 Live cd (promo cd) from gnome.org, how do I create bootable USB drive from it? I'm using Universal USB installer but don't know which distro to select from the list to create bootable USD drive. I tried latest version of OpenSUSE & Unlisted Linux ISO (new Syslinux) but none of them booted into GNOME 3.4 desktop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it wasn't mentioned on GNOME website that on which distro GNOME 3.4 live cd is based, trying random distros didn't worked, however, GNOME 3.0 live cd was launched based on both OpenSUSE and Fedora, so trying **Fedora 16 Desktop** as distro in Universal USB Installer worked for GNOME 3.4 live cd. But GNOME website could have listed distro type on website.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNetbooting](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) it has an easy GUI to create bootable live USB drives.

If you want more control over the boot loader or just want to do it yourself, you can also try the great [GRUB4DOS](http://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/).

Note that there is also a simple method for nix users described on the [Getting GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/getting-gnome/) page where you can also download the GNOME 3.4 images.